# onClickListener does not hide my text

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

**MainActivity**

```
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textID);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        tv.setText(R.string.text); 
    }
}
```

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="text">This text do not hide!</string>
</resources>
```

This code is directly showing the text which I will try to show when I click the button.

My question is, where am I making the mistake? Why does this code not work?

Comment: I don't see any code that is supposed to hide anything

Comment: I mean at the start of the application shouldn't this text appear when I click the button?

Comment: in general it should, but it depends on your layout. You might made your TextView invisible, or put it under something, or off screen, or other 1000 reasons.

Comment: onClick set an empty string tv.setText("")

Comment: maybe you hide it in xml file?
so on click you should also do  `tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to hide a view :

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for ex.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

to empty `TextView` :

```
tv.setText("");
```

for ex.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    tv.setText(""); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not explained my issue. I just want to show the text when I click the button. Not show it instantly when the application begins.

Comment: <TextView android:visibility="gone"  android:text="Hidden text" /> and then on click -> tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: 2nd way : -  <TextView android:text="" />   and then on click ->  tv.setText("visible text");

Answer (score 0):

To **hide** a view do  that:

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want only **remove text** do that:

```
tv.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

First inside `onCreate()` method

add

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

After that click on button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv.setText(R.string.text); 
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for hiding your TextView..

use `tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` 
or `tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

and if u want to set nothing on your textView than 
use `tv.setText("");`

Answer (score 0):

Use `getString()` method to get string from resources.

Try this,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    tv.setText(getString(R.string.bilmece_cevabi));
}
```